# VSTS GIT - PR from master -> dev

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Whenever I merge master branch down to development branch (or vice vs.) in VSTS git integration I keep seeing the same changes that were already merged. So for instance this morning I merged changes from master back to development. Merged, and then created another PR from master to development again and those same changes are showing in the PR again. Shouldn't there be no changes between the branches now?

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or what screen shots could be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finish merging `master` into `development` branch, then you merge `development` branch back into `master` branch, the code of the two branches will be same.

Assume the branch structure looks as below graph after merging `master` branch into `development` branch:

```
A---B---C---D---H   development
     \         /
      E---F---G     master
```

Then if you create another PR to merge `development` back into `master` by VSTS, VSTS will use create another commit by default as commit `I` in below graph instead of using commit `H` even it’s fast forward merge (`git merge master --no-ff`):

```
A---B---C---D---H      development
     \         / \
      E---F---G---I    master
```

But it’s not influence `master` branch sync with `development` branch.

If you want `master` branch point to the same commit as `development` branch (as `H` in below graph):

```
A---B---C---D---H   development, master
     \         / 
      E---F---G
```

You can merge `development` into `master` locally (`git checkout master` and `git merge  development`) and then push local `master` to remote, then both `development` branch and `master` branch will point to the same commit `H`.

Comment: I think this would work, but I think the issue I found is it was defaulting to squash merge so it was taking all my commits and merging them as one. When I would go to merge again it wouldn't have knowledge about all the individual commits so it would try and bring them in again.